# How to get Time zone name from DateTime.Now

Tags: c#

How to get time zone name(eg : Europe/London, Asia/Kolkata, etc.) from **DateTime.Now()** in c#

Please help me

Thanks,
King

Comment: You don't. DateTime instances are not TimeZone aware. They have a flag that indicates if they are local, utc, or unknown. If local then you need to get the timezone for the context that it is executing in.

Comment: You can't. `DateTime` has no timezone information and definitely not the IANA timezone names

Comment: You can use [DateTimeOffset.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.now?view=net-5.0) to get a `DateTimeOffset` with the local timezone *offset*. To get a value with the IANA timezone name though, you'd have to use a library like NodaTime

Comment: Why do you specify that you need it from `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: Anything is fine for me. how to get timezone name from c#?

Comment: Console.WriteLine( TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now) ? TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName : TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName);

Comment: @chandu_king there's no `anything is fine` when there's *no* timezone info in a `DateTime. `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` will return the local *Windows* timezone name, not the IANA timezone name. That timezone is specified in the user's locale settings so it's not affected by time. Only the display name (standard vs summer) is affected. There's no direct mapping between Windows and IANA timezone names in all cases though

Comment: Here's a man who knows a bit about timezones, if you're looking for IANA on Windows: https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter

Comment: Actually i need to pass Dotnet server timezone to PHP date_default_timezone_set() where it will accepts only this format eg. 'Europe/London' . How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now() returns current computer localtime.

If you want get current computer timezone, read this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't get zone using DateTime.Now()

The below piece of code gives you the daylight time and standard time .

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```